# Finite boolean algebra can be embedded into $\mathcal P(n)$.

Tags: boolean-algebra

I am trying to show that every finite boolean algebra can be embedded into $\mathcal P(n)$ for some large $n$. Any hints?

Comment: Embedded? How? With what structure? If just as a set, then isn't it obvious?

Comment: @MPW: As a Boolean algebra, obviously.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Sorry for my ignorance, but what is the natural structure on $\mathcal P(n)$?

Comment: @MPW: If $X$ is any set, $\wp(X)$ is a Boolean algebra with respect to the operations $\cap$ and $\cup$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Hmm...okay, guess I'll invest some time in reading up on Boolean algebraic structures. Never heard of 'em. EDIT: And yes, I probably shouldn't have commented in the first place.

Comment: @MPW: They’re pretty important algebraic structures, both in theory and in the real world. The Wikipedia articles [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_%28structure%29) with their links and references are one quick starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Let $B$ be a finite Boolean algebra. Let $A$ be the set of atoms of $B$. Show that every $b\in B$ is uniquely determined by $\{a\in A:a\le b\}$. What are the atoms of $\wp(n)$?

Comment: Therefore I must set $n=|A|$, let $f: A \rightarrow n$ be a bijection and define $h: B \rightarrow \mathcal P(n)$ be given by $h(b)=f[\{a \in A: a \leq b\}]$, right? :)

Comment: @Vinicius: You’ve got it. (By the way, I just realized that Artur Tomita’s mathematical ‘great-grandmother’ is my *Doktormutter*.)